# authorization library for common lisp

Tags: authorization, common-lisp

I'm looking for authorization library for common lisp, like [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) or [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit) for web aplication in web frameworks like, caveman, lucerne or radiance exists for authentication, or cl-oauth, but I couldn't find anything on quicklisp. any advice could help

Comment: You could have more chance on reddit. If you find one, don't forget to add it on the [awesome-cl](https://github.com/CodyReichert/awesome-cl) list :]

Comment: I will check reddit, maybe it is time to start using it ;-) also

Comment: What did you end up using? I am building an app using Ningle/Caveman2 and Clack and am looking for am implementation of authentication/authorization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Radiance has a [specific interface for authentication](https://github.com/Shirakumo/radiance#22-auth). Currently only one standard implementation is offered for this, called [r-simple-auth](https://github.com/Shirakumo/radiance-contribs/tree/master/r-simple-auth), which uses a password scheme to authenticate users. r-simple-auth should be loaded automatically when you depend on the auth interface in your application.

If you are looking for *authorization* instead, that is handled through the [user](https://github.com/Shirakumo/radiance#212-user) interface and the [check](https://shirakumo.github.io/radiance/#USER:CHECK), [grant](https://shirakumo.github.io/radiance/#FUNCTION%20USER%3AGRANT), etc. functions. Again, a standard implementation is offered for this interface, so you should be able to just start using it.

Comment: Ok, I definetively start using radiance, it looks great if it has authorization for resources, I will do the tutorial, thans for answering and also for doing that great job in common lisp librarires